# why do i get a syntax error when using commas inside a dictionary even though im suposed to use them

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, syntax-error

I'm writing my first program in python and i tried to do a dictionary for the operations in a calculator but IDLE says there is a syntax error in the first comma after the + sign. i have searched in the documentation for the proper syntax and it says i have to use commas. but they don't work

```
operations = {"plus":+,
              "minus":-,
              "times":*,
              "divided":/
              }
```

I have searched online, and tried everything but i can't figure it out.

Comment: thanks to everyone that answered! you guys helped me a lot.

Comment: Did any of the posts solve your question? if so, please don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, just click on the check mark to its left. Also worth reading: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use +,-,*,/ this way. They are operators. If you want to choose an operation the fast way is to use if conditions

```
a = input()
b = input()
res = 0

if op == "plus":
  res = a+b
elif op == "minus":
  res = a-b

print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

While others have already provided a few different ways i am just throwing this in for variety, i have not tested how efficent it may or may not be. It uses lambda as an annonymous function to return the value

```py
operations = {"plus":lambda a,b: a+b,
              "minus":lambda a,b: a-b,
              "times":lambda a,b: a*b,
              "divided":lambda a,b: a/b
              }

print(operations["plus"](10,15))
print(operations["minus"](50,15))
print(operations["times"](10,5))
print(operations["divided"](100,20))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
25
35
50
5.0
```